# Does MATLAB provide a lossless coversion function from double to string?

Tags: string, matlab, type-conversion, precision, chararray

### tl;dr

I'm just looking for two functions, `f` from `double` to `string` and `g` from `string` to `double`, such that `g(f(d)) == d` for any double `d` (scalar and real `double`).

### Original question

How do I convert a `double` to a `string` or `char` array in a reversible way? I mean, in such a way that afterward I can convert that `string`/`char` array back to `double` retrieving the original result.

I've found [`formattedDisplayText`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/formatteddisplaytext.html), and in some situations it works:

```matlab
>> x = eps

x =

     2.220446049250313e-16

>> double(formattedDisplayText(x, 'NumericFormat', 'long')) - x

ans =

     0
```

But in others it doesn't

```matlab
x = rand(1)

x =

   0.546881519204984

>> double(formattedDisplayText(x, 'NumericFormat', 'long')) - x

ans =

     1.110223024625157e-16
```

As regards this and other tools like [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html?searchHighlight=num2str&s_tid=srchtitle), [`mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html?s_tid=doc_ta), at the end they all require me to decide a precision, whereas I would like to express the idea of "use whatever precision is needed for you (MATLAB) to be able to read back your own number".

Comment: `mat2str` is supposed to do exactly what you want, it can even preserve the numeric type. You don’t need to specify a precision, you shouldn’t specify a precision.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, and what is its reverse operation? `str2double(mat2str(eps)) - eps` is not zero, so `str2double` is not good for reading that string back to the number it came from. The doc reads _`A = eval(chr)` reproduces the values from the original matrix to the precision specified in `chr`_, but  `eval(mat2str(eps)) - eps` is also not zero.

Comment: Hummm, interesting. You should report that as a bug, since it's not what the documentation describes.

Comment: It seems like it uses one digit too few. `eval(mat2str(eps,16))-eps` works correctly. 16 digits is enough for every possible double value. If you are dealing with values of other types, it'll get more complex. `mat2str` was supposed to take that complexity away.

Comment: Type `edit mat2str` in MATLAB, and you can see the implementation. At the top it says `precision = 15;`. This should have been 16. Pretty careless. You can copy and modify the M-file to suit your needs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, based on what it should have been 16? I guess yours is getting close to be an answer :/

Comment: I was wrong, it needs to be 17 decimal digits: "The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision (2−53 ≈ 1.11 × 10−16). [...] If an IEEE 754 double-precision number is converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits, and then converted back to double-precision representation, the final result must match the original number." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Any 15-digit decimal number can be converted to double precision float without loss. Maybe this is why `mat2str` uses 15 there, someone got confused.

Comment: Would this trick work for you? (I don't know your use case). It uses the internal byte representation of `x`: `str = ['typecast(uint8(' mat2str(typecast(x, 'uint8'))  '),''' class(x) ''')']`. Check with `eval(str)-x`

Comment: Also, do you need a string/char vector that when _`eval`_'ed gives the number? Or are you more flexible with the function that should be applied to the string to produce the number?

Comment: @LuisMendo, I'm just looking for two functions, `f` from `double` to `string` and `g` from `string` to `double`, such that `g(f(d)) == d` for any `double` `d`.

Comment: Then `eval` can be avoided: As `f` use `str = mat2str(typecast(x, 'uint8'));`.  As `g` use `x_recovered = typecast(uint8(str2num(str)), 'double');`. Let me know if this suits your needs so I can post it as an answer

Comment: Also, does the answer need to handle complex-valued `x`? Or non-scalar `x`? (I suggest you edit your question to include that information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two simpler solutions to convert a single double value to a string and back without loss.

#### I want the string to be a human-readable representation of the number

Use [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) to obtain 17 decimal digits in string form, and [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to convert back:

```matlab
>> s = mat2str(x,17) 
s =
    '2.2204460492503131e-16'
>> y = str2double(s);
>> y==x
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Note that 17 digits are always enough to represent any [IEEE double-precision floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

#### I want a more compact string representation of the number

Use [`matlab.net.base64encode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.net.base64encode.html) to encode the 8 bytes of the number. Unfortunately you can only encode strings and integer arrays, so we type cast to some integer array (we use `uint8` here, but `uint64` would work too). We reverse the process to get the same double value back:

```matlab
>> s = matlab.net.base64encode(typecast(x,'uint8'))
s =
    'AAAAAAAAsDw='
>> y = typecast(matlab.net.base64decode(s),'double');
>> x==y
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Base64 encodes every 3 bytes in 4 characters, this is the most compact representation you can easily create. A more complex algorithm could likely convert into a smaller UTF-8-encoded string (which uses more than 6 bytes per displayable character).

Answer (score 3):

#### Function `f`: from double real-valued scalar `x` to char vector `str`

```
str = num2str(typecast(x, 'uint8'));
```

`str` is built as a string containing 8 numbers, which correspond to the bytes in the internal representation of `x`. The function [`typecast`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) extracts the bytes as a numerical vector, and [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) converts to a char vector with numbers separated by spaces.

#### Function `g`: from char vector `str` to double real-valued scalar `y`

```
y = typecast(uint8(str2double(strsplit(str))), 'double');
```

The char vector is split at spaces using [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html). The result is a cell array of char vectors, each of which is then interpreted as a number by [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html), which produces a numerical vector. The numbers are cast to [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) and then `typecast` interprets them as the internal representation of a double real-valued scalar.

Note that `str2double(strsplit(str))` is preferred over the simpler `str2num(str)`, because [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) internally calls [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), which is considered <s>evil</s> [bad practice](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/).

#### Example

```
>> format long
>> x = sqrt(pi)
x =
   1.772453850905516
>> str = num2str(typecast(x, 'uint8'))
str =
    '106  239  180  145  248   91  252   63'
>> y = typecast(uint8(str2double(strsplit(str))), 'double')
y =
   1.772453850905516
>> x==y
ans =
  logical
   1
```